# When you put your eye up to a microscope, why does the image get blury if you move your eye away?

Tags: optics, lenses, microscopy

I was thinking about it and I remember someone saying it had something to do with your eye having to be at the focal point. But that didn't make sense to me because the focal point would be the point where the image was super small and not magnified at all. The more I thought about it the more confused I became, because it seems to me, with my rudimentary understanding of how a lens works, that the further your "photon detector" was from the lens the better magnification you'd get because the rays diverge more and more (assuming you have a divergent lens). Yet I've googled and googled and I can't find anywhere that says anything like that. I've made a simple diagram in paint to illustrate what I mean by the image gets bigger:

[image]

Comment: You're confusing how big an image is (i.e. how big it would look on a _screen_) with how magnified it is (i.e. how big it would look if you put your eye there). What you're proposing is analogous to standing in front of a movie screen and looking at the projector. That doesn't give you a huge magnified image of the movie. You just see a blurry tiny piece of it, because your eye is small.

Comment: Do you understand what depth of focus and depth of field mean?

Comment: @Jon nope, no idea